# How to cancel/abort reading or writing a stream in the middle of transmission using Indy TCPServer?

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy

Please, how to cancel/abort reading or writing a stream in the middle of transmission using Indy TCPServer? I can't find an example anywhere...

Thanks!

Comment: The only way is to either raise an exception in the connection's `OnWork` events, or else close the socket connection (which you are likely going to have to do anyway).

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thank you! I wil do some tests here...

Comment: how about `raise EAbort.Create`?